# Variable instead of dataframe name in pandas function

Tags: python, pandas

I have something like

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_on='x', right_on='y')
```

But I would like the the two dataframes to be represented by variables instead:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df_var, df_var2, how='inner', left_on='x', right_on='y')
```

I get this error: ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type

I'm stuck on how to get pandas to recognize the variable as the name of the dataframe. thanks!

Comment: What are `df_var` and `df_var2`?

Comment: strings, for example: df_var = df_templates.board[df_templates['prog_code'] == program].to_string(index=False)

Comment: Why is the `.to_string(index=False)` necessary? Are you passing the DataFrame through something else?

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the dataframes in a dict and referencing them using the keys

```
df_dict = {var: df1, var2: df2}
df3 = pd.merge(df_dict[var], df_dict[var2], how='inner', left_on='x', right_on='y')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the DataFrames have been converted to strings, you need to convert them back to DataFrames before merging. Here's one way you could do it:

```
from io import StringIO

# to strings
df_var = df1.to_string(index=False)
df_var2 = df2.to_string(index=False)

# back to DataFrames
df_var = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_var))
df_var2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_var2))

df3 = pd.merge(df_var, df_var2, how='inner', left_on='x', right_on='y')
```